# Custom Google StreetView with markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I was wondering if you could put a custom StreetView with a marker. I am making a map that has city parks.  I want it so if someone clicks on a specific marker, the custom StreetView pops up and shows the panorama.  For the custom StreetViews I used Google Views. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Something close to it can be done in two ways.

The easiest option is to load Google maps from the main URL and wait. It will let you build a map or view your custom maps just below the search bar. Google Maps itself lets you create a custom map with markers. This doesn't sound like your desired option, but it is quick to implement. You can even add your own style.

The second is to create your own custom Street View tour, this sounds like your focus. You want the actual panographs to use your markers. This is fairly easy to do, but requires some programming. It is possible on both Google Earth and Google Maps. Check out the Google APIs such as https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions. Options include changing out panographs for your own images, defining arrows including labels, overlays, pop-up boxes, action boxes, and more. Check out some options here: http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples.html

Comment: You can also check out views: https://www.google.com/maps/views/view/streetview/poland-tourist-attractions/copernicus-science-centre-1/h6dW2ZVudZOdee4rXUMz_Q?hl=en&gl=pl&heading=214&pitch=84&fovy=75